# Problem: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

Using Visual Studio 2010, I am reporting on my local computer vith SAP Crystal Reports. Everything works on the local computer very well.

However, when I upload my project to highh security remote hosting after publishing the project, I get the specified warning as mentioned below.

In this case, I would like to ask; am I making a mistake in the coding or my Crystal Report versions is wrong? or this is the hosting server's company problem?

Thank you.

**Configuration Error**

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Source Error**:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

**Source File:** D:\IISDIRS\web.config    Line: 29

**Assembly Load Trace:** The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could not be loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The machine has a Crystal runtime engine that is incompatible with the way your application was built (the Crystal references in your application).

Reference/Version=13.0.2000.0 works with Crystal runtimes 0 to 24

Reference/Version=13.0.3500.0 works with Crystal runtimes 21 to 25

Reference/Version=13.0.4000.0 works with Crystal runtimes 26 and later (for now)

For example, if your Crystal references in your project show 13.0.2000.0, then you need to install Crystal runtime engine SP20.

If you need to remove a Crystal runtime engine service pack and install another, this link has great instructions for cleaning it up:

https://help.jeff-net.com/knowledgebase/article/uninstalling-a-crystal-runtime-service-pack-manually-removing-the-crystal-runtime-engine

Please be careful removing Crystal runtime engines, too. OTHER software may be dependent on a specific version. For example, SAGE apps only work with SP21 currently.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer John. I did as you said, but the last thing; Dll files need to be uploaded into the Bin folder after the project's compiled. Could you please give me some information on which files I will put into the Bin folder and how?

Comment: For Crystal, you don't put ANY files in the bin folder. You download the runtime engine you want to use from SAP. For example, if you're using Crystal runtime engine SP25, you would download the SP25 MSI installer from SAP. THAT installs all the necessary files for .Net to run the Crystal part of your app.